# Why is MSVC failing to compile when I separate the method's definition from its declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Separating a method's definition from its declaration when using a C++20 constrained template causes MSVC to fail to compile (GCC on the other hand compiles just fine). This, however, happens only if I don't specify the namespace that the concept belongs to, even if the method is also part of said namespace.

Is this a MSVC bug or am I writing invalid C++20 code?

Here's an example:

```
namespace Foo
{
    template<std::size_t N>
    class Bar;

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    concept BarConcept = requires (T t, const Foo::Bar<N>& bar)
    {
        { t(bar) } -> std::same_as<std::size_t>;
    };

    template<std::size_t N>
    class Bar
    {
    public:

        // Compiles
        template<Foo::BarConcept<N> T>
        std::size_t method0(T);

        // Fails
        template<BarConcept<N> T>
        std::size_t method1(T);

        // Compiles
        template<BarConcept<N> T>
        std::size_t method2(T t)
        {
            return t(*this) + 3;
        }
    };
}

template<std::size_t N>
template<Foo::BarConcept<N> T>
std::size_t Foo::Bar<N>::method0(T t)
{
    return t(*this) + 1;
}

template<std::size_t N>
template<Foo::BarConcept<N> T>
std::size_t Foo::Bar<N>::method1(T t)
{
    return t(*this) + 2;
}
```

Here is the error reported by MSVC:

```
error C2244: 'Foo::Bar<N>::method1': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
message : see declaration of 'Foo::Bar<N>::method1'
message : definition
message : 'size_t Foo::Bar<N>::method1(T)'
message : existing declarations
message : 'size_t Foo::Bar<N>::method1(T)'
```

Comment: I am not sure about this one but not all c++20 features are supported yet.

Comment: [Reproduced @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mrenqc)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not really. I'm still implementing the template in the header file, just separately from its declaration. And like I said, it works if I specify the namespace of the concept in the declaration.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, I know, but I feel like it's a bug, right? After all concepts seem to be working, and the code compiles if the namespace of the concept is specified in the declaration. I was just wondering if it's really a bug, or if I'm just being stupid and writing invalid c++20 code... Ultimately, yeah, it could be that the feature is still not fully supported.

Comment: I tried to make sense of it here but gave up a few minutes ago: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @drescherjm I gave it a look, and the only thing I found that could be related is feature "P1141R2 Yet another approach for constrained declarations" that's only partially implemented yet. However, when I open the attached link I didn't find anything related to namespaces. It could still be that tho.

Comment: naw that is a bug

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah, I'm inclined to believe that. Probably gonna report it.